# Get-AzureRmBackupVault not returning any error or result

Tags: powershell, azure, backup, azure-backup-vault

Still wondering why Azure Powershell is not consistently working.

I tried pulling all azure vault via powershell using following command line but none of result coming from this command :

Add-azurermaccount

Login-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXX-b8ee-4533-a2c2-3ee6b4f01a8d"

Get-AzureRmBackupVault

Same problem with many other powershell command like Get-AzureRmResourceGroup where otherside Get-AzureRmVM working fine.

Comment: You need to pass the name of the resource you are trying to get an error message.

Comment: You should update your modules, `Add-AzureRmAccount` is no longer a thing.

Comment: execuse me, whats wrong with `add-azurermaccount`? its working on the latest version of Azure PowerShell @TheMadTechnician; to the OP, delete all the Azure PowerShell modules and install latest versions

Comment: To run the command Get-AzureRMBackupvault you need PowerShell module 1.7.0 
Download the latest PowerShell module from the below link and retry the operation  
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.DataLakeStore/5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure you have a `Backup vault (classic)` in your subscription.

[image]

Backup Vault is a classic resource, if you create `Recovery Services vault`,

[image]

please execute following cmdlet.

```
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation).

Note: You could not use `Get-AzureRmBackupVault` to get Recovery Sevices Vault . It seems that you don't have backup vault(classic) in your subscription.

If you have Backup vault in your subscription, you could download and install the latest version Azure Power Shell from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: Hi, if you use the latest version Azure Power Shell, I am sure my answer will work for you. If possible, you could check it.

Comment: Version update did a trick but I did require me to logout and religion at machine for some reason.

Comment: @vj54 Do you check it on Azure Portal, the resource you want to get is `Backup vault(classic)` or `Recovery Services vault`? If possible, could you give me some screenshots about this?